# How to create BAK file from azure sql db

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-server

I want to move my azure sql db to another host. However my new host allows to import sql db backup-files (.BAK) only; 
I found out how to generate .BACPAK files with SQL Server Management Studio but I could not find a way to create a BAK-file from my azure sql db.
Please help.

Comment: **exact** duplicate of [make a backup for azure database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991354/make-a-backup-for-azure-database), including the answer...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> However my new host allows to import sql db backup-files (.BAK) only;

SQL Azure doesn't provide a native way to generate '.bak' format backup file. If you did need this format file, you could import the BACPAC File to a local SQL Server which supports importing BACPAC File. After that, a new User Database will be created. Then you could generate a '.bak' format file from the local SQL Server.

In addition, you also could try a tool named [SqlAzureBakMaker](https://github.com/shawnweisfeld/SqlAzureBakMaker) which could make '.bak' file for you easily.

Comment: This kills the purpose for me, I wanted the .bak file for index fragmentation to make tests on local. But it recreates indexes.

Answer (score 3):

**In Azure portal:**

1. In the SQL Server database page, click on 'Export'

[image]

2. Select a Storage Account and a Container, and click 'Ok'
3. Go to your Storage accounts page
4. Select the previously selected Storage account
5. At the sub-navigation-menu > Data-storage section > Containers > select the used Container
6. You should find the exported .bac file shortly after, you can download it.
   [image]

**Hope it helps.**