# Backup Azure Database to .BAK file using SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

I have an Azure Database backed up as a `.bacpac` file.

However, my new hosting platform does not allow `.bacpac` imports.  (only `.bak`)

I was wondering if it were possible to backup to a `.bak` file, using SSMS.

If not, is it possible to convert a `.bacpac` to a `.bak`?

I'm going to add 1 more thing to this...

After research, I understand this is possible with SQL Server.  (not SSMS)

Does anyone know if it's possible to do a `.bak` backup with SQL Server 2014 Express?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create BAK file from azure sql db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447391/how-to-create-bak-file-from-azure-sql-db)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create BAK file from azure sql db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447391/how-to-create-bak-file-from-azure-sql-db)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so after some research... Here is the solution that worked for me:

First, download SQL Server 2014 Express, from Microsoft  (Or whatever version/instance you prefer)

[Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299)

Next, set it up correctly by watching this very helpful YouTube Video:

[YouTube SQL Server 2014 Express Setup Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_zFM7mzFUg)

**Note:** You will also need a version of SSMS, which you can also do/figure out by watching the YouTube video.

Then, on your Azure account (or wherever your Database is that doesn't allow you to create a `.BAK` file is, do the following)

Connect to it and navigate to Tasks > Export Data-tier Application.

Save that to your computer.  (That will give you a `.bacpac` file.)

Next, connect to your "local" SQL Server instance.

Then, Import data-tier Application.  (Will need the `.bacpac` file)

Lastly, (after fully imported) you will now have the option to do Tasks > Back Up

This will allow you to save a local file as a `.BAK` file!

Then, just upload this file to your new hosting platform.

This worked like a charm for me.  :-)

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but what if you want to update the data from Azure to on-prem on a regular basis? Or does Azure do this automatically now because the onprem restore is connected to Azure?

Answer (score 0):

.bacpac contains less information than .bak file, for example no transaction logs. Best approach would be to restore backpac on some other server and then create backup.